# NameError: name 'fcntl' is not defined

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pudb

I've installed `PuDB` on `python 3.4.2` which is in `virtualenv` and running on `windows 7 sp1`.

I first activate virtualenv

```
workon env01
```

then enter to python console

```
python
```

now I need to test PuDB as following

```
>>> import pudb
>>> pudb.set_trace()
```

and I get this error

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in
> <module>   File
> "C:\Users\L3\Envs\env01\lib\site-packages\pudb\__init__.py", line 150,
> in set_trace
>     dbg = _get_debugger()   File "C:\Users\L3\Envs\env01\lib\site-packages\pudb\__init__.py", line 35,
> in _get_debugger
>     dbg = Debugger(**kwargs)   File "C:\Users\L3\Envs\env01\lib\site-packages\pudb\debugger.py", line 150,
> in __init__
> 
>    self.ui = DebuggerUI(self, stdin=stdin, stdout=stdout, term_size=term_size)   File
> "C:\Users\L3\Envs\env01\lib\site-packages\pudb\debugger.py", line
> 1871, in __init__
>     self.screen = ThreadsafeRawScreen()   File "C:\Users\L3\Envs\env01\lib\site-packages\urwid\raw_display.py", line
> 89, in __init__
>     fcntl.fcntl(self._resize_pipe_rd, fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK) NameError: name 'fcntl' is not defined
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: PuDb uses urwid, which does not appear to support Microsoft's Windows except under Cygwin:  http://urwid.org  (see "Requirements")

Comment: I've installed and used Cygwin, but still get the same error

Comment: It looks like the module is installed in a Windows environment, rather than a Cygwin environment.  The problem here is that `fcntl` is UNIX specific, it is not available on Windows.