# 'NameError: name 'fcntl' is not defined' when using urwid on windows

Tags: python, urwid

So I just installed Urwid and as a test tried running the Urwid equivalent of a basic print command, as given as an example on the Urwid website tutorial. I received an error message.

I tried running a different one of the examples and received a similar error message. The code looks like this:

```
import urwid

txt = urwid.Text(u"Hello World")
fill = urwid.Filler(txt, 'top')
loop = urwid.MainLoop(fill)
loop.run()
```

It should print 'Hello World' in the top left corner of the screen and then run until instructed to quit. Instead I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rory Kranz\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.34.0\testingg", line 5, in <module>
    loop = urwid.MainLoop(fill)
  File "C:\Users\Rory Kranz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urwid\main_loop.py", line 114, in __init__
    screen = raw_display.Screen()
  File "C:\Users\Rory Kranz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urwid\raw_display.py", line 92, in __init__
    fcntl.fcntl(self._resize_pipe_rd, fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)
NameError: name 'fcntl' is not defined
```

Did something go wrong with the installation, or is there something else I need to install in order to get Urwid to work?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use [urwid](http://urwid.org/), you will need to use it with [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) (not sure of [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/) supports it but it might be worth a try if that's your preference).

Windows does not natively support the [fcntl](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl)  interface and apparently it is not trivial to simulate it using win32 functions.

If you want to remain on windows without a unix emulation environment, you might try [curses](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/curses.html) or [python prompt toolkit](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit). I can't be sure these are the best choices as I'm not clear on what exactly you are trying to do.

Some relevant links

[Problem over windows platform](https://github.com/urwid/urwid/issues/152)
[NameError: name 'fcntl' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40355521/nameerror-name-fcntl-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is outdated. Windows does not support the interface however installing the new Linux bash console will suffice.

Comment: Do you mean WSL2? If so, could you provide a link and instructions/summary of the link?